# ValueError: could not convert string to float in simple code

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, floating-point

```
       # -*- coding: cp1250 -*-
print ('euklides alpha 1.0')
a = raw_input('podaj liczbę A  : ')
b = raw_input('podaj liczbę B  : ')

a = float('a')
b = float('b')

if 'a'=='b':
    print 'a'
elif 'a' > 'b':
    while 'a' > 'b':
        print('a'-'b')
        if 'a'=='b': break
        if 'a' > 'b': continue
elif 'b' > 'a':
    while 'b' > 'a':
        print('b'-'a')
        if 'b'=='a': break
        if 'b' > 'a': continue
```

So, this is a code, which I made few hours ago. Now I get a `ValueError: could not convert string to float: a`, and I have no idea why. Can you explain it to me? I'm a beginner.

Comment: Why are you making everything strings? `'a'` is the character `a` - `a` (no quotes) is the variable name `a`... So `float('a')` is wrong - you can't make a float from the letter `a` - it should be `float(a)` where `a` will be the content of what's been entered...

Comment: ohhhhhhhh yes, now I see it, than you for support :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're enclosing all your variables in single quotes, so you're comparing the string `"a"` with the string `"b"` rather than the floating point number contained in variable `a` with the same in variable `b`

Also worth pointing out:

**This is your original code, to request two floating point numbers from the user**

```
a = raw_input('podaj liczbę A  : ')
b = raw_input('podaj liczbę B  : ')
a = float(a)
b = float(b)
```

**If you're in Python 2.x, you can instead use**

I was corrected by [abarnert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/908494/abarnert) in comments below. Just leaving it for edification:

> I wouldn't suggest using input instead of raw_input and float. The latter guarantees that you get floats; the former could get, say, the result of calling `__import__('os').system('rm -rf /')`, which is probably something you don't want

```
a = input('podaj liczbę A  : ')
b = input('podaj liczbę A  : ')
```

**If you're not, you may want to include a try/catch block that will force the variable to be of the type you require**

```
a_verifying = True
while a_verifying:
  a = input('podaj liczbę A  : ')
  try:
    a = float(a)
    a_verifying = False
  except ValueError as e:
    a = input('podaj liczbę A  : ')

b_verifying = True
while b_verifying:
  b = input('podaj liczbę B  : ')
  try:
    b = float(b)
    b_verifying = False
  except ValueError as e:
    b = input('podaj liczbę B  : ')
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using `input` instead of `raw_input` and `float`. The latter guarantees that you get floats; the former could get, say, the result of calling `__import__('os').system('rm -rf /')`, which is probably something you don't want.

Comment: abarnert: I defer to your opinion. I only started using Python recently, and when I started I learned "input() for numbers, raw_input() for strings." Now I'm in 3.x and don't care about such distinctions :)

Answer (score 2):

the float function can take a string but it must contain a possibly signed decimal or floating point number. You want to make the variable `a` a float not the char `'a'`.

You don't need all the `'` around your variable names. When you put quotes around them `'b'` you are making them a string.

On another note once you reach on of those `while` statements there's nothing that will get you out of there.

```
a = float(a)


if a == b: # you need to get rid of all the ' unless you are talking about chars 



   # -*- coding: cp1250 -*-
print ('euklides alpha 1.0')
a = raw_input('podaj liczbę A  : ')
b = raw_input('podaj liczbę B  : ')

a = float('a')
b = float('b')

if a==b:
    print a
elif a > b:
    while a > b: # nothing will get you out of the while loop
        print(a-b)
        if a == b:
            break
        if a > b: # no need for this if, the while loop will do that check for you
            continue
elif b > a:
    while b > a: # nothing will get you out of the while loop
        print(b-a)
        if b==a:
            break
        if b > a: # no need for this if, the while loop will do that check for you
            continue
```